# Open a repository on virtualbox by local editor or git GUI clients

Tags: git, vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

I'd like to open a repository on a VirtualBox,accessed by Vagrant, by local editor or git GUI clients(ex Source Tree).

I've edited the Vagrantfile as following, then type $vagrant reload.

I thought that it would have let me access the repository on a virtualbox from local, however it couldn't. Could you tell me how to solve the problem?

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
......

  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant"
    type: "rsync",
    owner: "vagrant",
    group: "vagrant",
    rsync__exclude: [".git/", "vendor/"]

  ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using rysnc-back, I've solve the problem. Thank your for your help.
https://github.com/smerrill/vagrant-rsync-back